# Copying other answers

Tags: discussion, answers

I've noticed a trend where some users post an answer as early as possible that's not very good but gets some up-votes. Then when better answers are posted, they simply copy/paste the contents of those answers, perhaps re-wording them a little, into their own.

Sometimes they even thank the person they are ripping-off for help with improving their answer. If that person had wanted to improve their answer, they would have edited it instead of posting their own.

This practice should be discouraged.

Related: [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: How about a case like [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/139167/switching-out-old-broken-shaver-socket-for-new-one-having-trouble-working-out-h/167975#167975), where the question was answered in its comments, but never received an actual answer? It was a good question, with a good answer, but it remained "unanswered" for over a year.  I simply put the comments into a "real" answer.  Was that legitimate, or something I shouldn't have done?

Comment: In that case it seems okay, although you could also up-vote the comments.

Answer (score 4):

What you have described is plagiarism.  Copying the entirety of someone else's answer is plagiarism, whether cited or not.  Flag it as such, with a proper description of what happened, and what the post is plagiarizing.

Of course if someone is using the ideas of another answer (with citation) to augment and improve *their own original answer*, then that's neither plagiarism nor otherwise problematic.  Creating a derived work of another answer that meaningfully improves on it is of course encouraged.

Comment: I would suggest that if they want to augment their own answer it would be better to say something like "see also X's answer", rather than just ripping off their work. In most cases where they could add to the answer it would be better to either post a comment or edit it directly, rather than just duplicating it in part.

Comment: @user Answers are expected to be complete, stand alone answers, and are expected to not rely on links to other content to actually answer the question.  If the post is simply using some of another answer to augment their own, and then no, that is not appropriate as an edit or a comment, that's *providing their own answer*.  Editing one's own answer into someone else's is not appropriate, nor is posting an answer as a comment.

Comment: what I mean is, if you realize you could improve someone else's argument you should improve it, not copy it into your own and amend it there.

Comment: @user If you want to make an aesthetic improvement, to fix some grammatical or formatting errors, or correct a simple typo to what the author clearly intended to have written, yes.  If you want to meaningfully change the solution it's presenting, then such an edit is prohibited.

Comment: in which case a comment to help them improve the answer seems best.

Comment: @user Posting one's own answer to provide a meaningful improvement of another answer is entirely appropriate.  While you're welcome to try to convince someone to change their answer via comments, it's sometimes not practical, given the nature of the change, and certainly not required.